# ¿Cómo obtener la primera letra que se ingresa en un textbox?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

Tengo un textbox llamado (**txtNumeroMovil**) y un botón llamado (**Button1**). Lo que deseo, es comprobar que cuando se hace clic en el **Button1** me valide que la primera letra que se ingresó en el **textbox** sea el número **9**, en caso contrario que la primera letra ingresada no es el **9** me muestre un mensaje (**Primera letra no es el 9**).

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      ///<!---Validar primera letra------>
   if(//Si la primera letra es el 9)
   {
        MessageBox.Show("Primera letra es el 9");
   }
   else
   {
        MessageBox.Show("Primera letra no es el 9");
   }
}
```

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad `Text` para leer el contenido del textbox, y luego puedes obtener el primer caracter usando el string como un arreglo, o sea leyendo el caracter en el primer índice:

```
if (txtNumeroMovil.Text[0] == '9')
```

Y si quieres evitar un error si el textbox está vacío, puedes agregar una verificación adicional:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNumeroMovil.Text) && txtNumeroMovil.Text[0] == '9')
```

Otra posibilidad mas compacta, que reemplaza las 2 condiciones arriba, es usando LINQ:

```
if (txtNumeroMovil.Text.FirstOrDefault() == '9')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @sstan, me funcionó perfectamente.

Comment: Tambien podria ser una posibilidad que se desactiven los demas numeros al principio y una vez introducido el 9 se vuelvan a activar?

Comment: Cómo lo hago?, ¿Podría ser con el KeyPress?